# Sending Mass Mail is too slow via PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send mass mail via PHP mail() function but it is too slow. All the emails are fetched from database. Currently, I am performing this with Xampp (offline) with Sendmail. And right now in my database there are only 6 emails and it is taking 2 mins to complete sending all the mails. I am just worried about what what will happen when in production mode there will be thousands of users. A sample code is given below about what I am using. Is there any way of making it execute faster?

```
$from    = (!empty($_POST['from']))?$_POST['from']:null;
$type    = (!empty($_POST['type']))?$_POST['type']:null;
$to      = (!empty($_POST['to']))?$_POST['to']:null;
$subject = (!empty($_POST['subject']))?$_POST['subject']:null;
$message = (!empty($_POST['message']))?$_POST['message']:null;

if($_POST){
    $emails = $pdo->prepare("SELECT mem_email FROM members");
    $emails-> execute();

    $adminMail = $pdo->prepare("SELECT set_site_name, set_admin_support_mail FROM settings");
    $adminMail-> execute();
    $amf = $adminMail->fetch();

    $headers = "From: ".$from." (".$amf['set_admin_support_mail'].")";

    while($u = $emails->fetch()){
      $sendTo = $u['mem_email']; // note the comma

      mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use mail() for this as it never was meant for this kind of work. Use a third party system designed to send bulk emails.

Comment: @JohnConde can you tell me a good one?

Comment: This could be a blessing in disguise. Most hosts will limit the number of emails you send within an Minute/Hour/Day and 6 in 2 minutes seems like a safe number

Comment: Mailgun is a good third party service for sending mails

Comment: something that is easy to implement and super fast?

Comment: @RiggsFolly so waiting 2 days to send 10000 emails is safest?

Comment: Sending mass mail it's a nightmare. First, this delay you experience is not a PHP problem in a decent well managed Linux environment. Second, if you send mass mail you' be banned ASAP, mails will only reach SPAM folder unless you are well recognize legitimate institution and your mail server is configured by ninjas. I'll take a look to Mailgun and its API first, or similar.

Comment: 1) Show mail sending configuration from your php config 2) Will you use smtp server on the same unix/linux host (localhost) in production?  Do not loose your faith in the power of reconfiguration! ;-)

Comment: I got rid of a similar issue by using PHPMailer instead of mail().  But @JohnConde suggestion`s is the real McCoy

Comment: Read [the PHPMailer wiki docs on sending to lists](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists). mail() is not only less secure, it's also slow. SMTP to localhost (or nearby decent mail server) works best. I sustain over 600,000 messages/hour that way, but I do know what I'm doing and it's not especially easy - it is easier to outsource the problem.